# Add a tag for Sequence-Kinetics

Tags: support

I'd like to add a tag for Sequence-Kinetics (and Sequence V6 if possible) to Stack Overflow. It's a workflow management tool but there's very little info out there other than the vendor's website and forum.

According to other similar questions about adding a tag the accepted answer seems to be to ask here if you don't have enough rep to do it yourself. Apologies if this isn't the correct way.

***UPDATE***

Here's the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431733/why-would-an-image-not-be-displayed-in-sequence-kinetics-but-would-be-in-sequenc)

Comment: What tags do you want added to which questions?

Comment: @Cerbrus - I've not posted the question as it's specific to Sequence-Kinetics. As there's no tag I didn't see the point in writing the question. However, I thought that if the tag could be created then I could post my question and tag it. Do I need to post the question first and then tag it once the tag is created? The tags would be sequence-kinetics and sequence-v6.

Comment: As far as I know, tags can only be created when they're added to a question.

Comment: @sr28 There has to be an existing question for another user to create the tag for you. If you had the rep for it, you'd be able to just create the tag yourself when posting the question. In other words, you should post the question first, then post the link to it here and someone with the rep for it can edit your question to add the tags.

Comment: @Kendra - updated with a link to the question

Comment: @Cerbrus - updated with link.

Comment: Can you add some tag wiki text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags created!

The tag wiki's are still empty, though.

Comment: Thanks. I've added an excerpt for Sequence Kinetics, though I don't have privileges to create it so it's in a queue. I'll do something similar for V6.